# Create or copy a dynamic amount of Shape3DObjects

Tags: java, simulation, anylogic

is it possible to create a dynamic amount of Shape3DObjects at the beginning of a Simulation using Java? Or is it even possible to create or clone them during a running Simulation?

I tried to do it while running the Simulation by including a button with this code:

```
Shape3DObject factory2 = new Shape3DObject(
    Main.this, SHAPE_DRAW_2D3D, true, 100.0, 100.0, 0.0, 0.0,
        1.25, true, "/model6/",
        "x3d/factory.x3d", OBJECT_3D_YZX_AXIS_ORDER, true, -125.0, -70.0,
        247.0, 140.0, null );
```

Sadly didn't do anything.

Comment: often, you have to add it to the presentation after creation, something like getPresentation().add(factory2);

Comment: just presentation.add( factory2 );

Comment: Thanks, that did work out fine.